# Is the ESTA still valid after receiving F1 visa?

Tags: usa, visa, student-visa, esta

I have visited the US for a couple of days in 2018 under the Visa Waiver Program, after obtaining an ESTA. Afterwards, I became a student and got a F1 visa.

Now, I've left the US after withdrawing from the program (and therefore losing my F1 visa).

I need to visit the US for a week-long business meeting. Can I use the ESTA I got in 2018, which is supposed to be valid for two years? Or did receiving the F1 visa (and losing it) invalidate my ESTA?